# Maximizing particle annihilation of a certain particle type?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, special-relativity, particle-physics, statistical-mechanics

Is there any theoretical situation where one would be able to maximize the production of a certain type of particle?

I wish to continue discussing this question:
[Where would dark matter be produced?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/194198/where-would-dark-matter-be-produced/194223#194223) . Kyle Oman gave an excellent answer, which lead me to the next question, this time about particle physics (field I am weak in):

**Question**

If we have the hypothetical reactions:

$e^+ + e^- \rightarrow Z + Z$

$e^+ + e^- \rightarrow X + X$

$e^+ + e^- \rightarrow Y + Y$,

where $e^+$, $e^-$ are positron and electron, and $Y$, $X$, $Z$ are some particles. **Assume** a large amount of $e^+$, $e^-$; *would it be possible to create a theoretical situation where $e^+ + e^- \rightarrow X + X$ production is maximized based on the particle $X$ properties and e.g. momentum of $e^+$, $e^-$, while not maximizing the production of $Y,Z$?*

I would appreciate sources/further reading, and if the question is too general I can modify it.

Comment: One can prepare spin and kinetic energy of the particles $-$ if their kinetic energy is low enough, then only 2, 3 or more photons will be produced (depending on the particle spins $-$ see [Positronium](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Positronium)), because there's not enough energy to create other massive particles. When the impact energy is increased by speeding up the particles like in an accelerator, then other massive particles may pop out and it's hard to control its final outcome due to small associated de Broglie wavelength, i.e. the mutual coherence of the particles. That much I know.

Comment: It strongly depends on the form of the interactions.

Comment: Thank you @gox ; would you know if it is theoretically possible to maximize the massive particle production which only occurs at higher energies, while keeping e.g. photon production to a minimum?

Comment: I am not an expert, sorry. Post the question again in slightly different form (e.g. "particle annihilation without photons"), maybe someone competent will find it challenging enough.

Comment: @gox Ill try to make a bit more effort solving it myself first ;) cheers